# Passing SQl queries in R shiny Date range

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a SQL query function. When I run below code in SQL I get the output.

```
select * FROM [DB].[dbo].[Customer] ('Num', '2008-01-01', '2009-01-01') order by [Date] desc
```

But I need this to be run R shiny as per the date I select from dateInput. So The code goes like this

```
data1 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select * from [DB].[dbo].[Customer] ('Num', FirstDate = input$Date[1] AND SecondDate = input$Date[2]) order by [Date]  desc")
```

Here Num, FirstDate and SecondDate are parameters written in SQL so I am calling them. But I am not able to run the above query in R. Can anyone please help me

Comment: Hi all, Can anyone please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Since the query needs to be within quotes, you may want to rely on `paste` or `paste0`.

```
sql<-paste0("select * FROM [DB].[dbo].[Customer] ('Num', ",input$Date1," ,", input$Date2,") order by [Date] desc")

data1 <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, query)
```

Comment: Thanks will try. But is it input$Date1 or input$Date[1] ?

Comment: I tried. but i am getting 0 rows. I mean empty table.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a code with a reproducible example or if you have a git repo?